# White box plot in seaborn? (not transparent on overlay)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, boxplot

I want to create a plot in seaborn with a custom background color and on top of it to plot some white boxplots. Instead, when they are set to white they are basically transparent.

This is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

with open('Data_Figure.csv', 'r') as handle:
    data_plot = pandas.read_csv(handle, sep='\t')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,6), dpi=600)

ax.axvspan(-0.5, 0.5, facecolor='#FFFFCC', alpha=0.3)
ax.axvspan(0.5, 1.5, facecolor='#FFE600', alpha=0.3)
ax.axvspan(1.5, 2.5, facecolor='#999900', alpha=0.3)

g1 = sns.boxplot(x="Group", y="ORIG – MTP 405nm average", hue="Type", palette = ['w'],
                 fliersize=0, width=0.5, medianprops=dict(color="red", alpha=1), boxprops=dict(linewidth=1, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k', alpha=1), 
                 whiskerprops=dict(linewidth=0.75, color='k', alpha=1), capprops=dict(linewidth=0.5, color='k', alpha=1),
                 data=data_plot, ax=ax)
plt.legend()
```

Instead, I get the following. With the inside of the boxes being as the background. Maybe I should use a different method to create the background? Or there should be a specification on the order of the layers?

[image: White background is transparent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boxes have `zorder` 0 whereas the yellow background patches have `zorder` 1 and hence will be plotted *over* the boxes.

You can specifiy the zorder of the patches, e.g. set it to -1:

```
ax.axvspan(-0.5, 0.5, facecolor='#FFFFCC', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
ax.axvspan(0.5, 1.5, facecolor='#FFE600', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
ax.axvspan(1.5, 2.5, facecolor='#999900', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
```